# Is do-notation specific to "base:GHC.Base.Monad"?

Tags: haskell, monads, ghc

The idea that the standard `Monad` class is flawed and that it should actually extend `Functor` or `Pointed` is floating around.

I'm not necessarily claiming that it is the right thing to do, but suppose that one was trying to do it:

```
import Prelude hiding (Monad(..))

class Functor m => Monad m where
    return :: a -> m a
    join :: m (m a) -> m a
    join = (>>= id)
    (>>=) :: m a -> (a -> m b) -> m b
    a >>= t = join (fmap t a)
    (>>) :: m a -> m b -> m b
    a >> b = a >>= const b
```

So far so good, but then when trying to use do-notation:

```
whileM :: Monad m => m Bool -> m ()
whileM iteration = do
    done <- iteration
    if done
        then return ()
        else whileM iteration
```

The compiler complains:

```
Could not deduce (base:GHC.Base.Monad m) from the context (Monad m)
```

**Question:**

Does do-notation work only for `base:GHC.Base.Monad`? Is there a way to make it work with an alternative `Monad` class?

**Extra context:**

What I really want to do is replace `base:Control.Arrow.Arrow` with a "generalized" `Arrow` class:

```
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies #-}

class Category a => Arrow a where
    type Pair a :: * -> * -> *
    arr :: (b -> c) -> a b c
    first :: a b c -> a (Pair a b d) (Pair a c d)
    second :: a b c -> a (Pair a d b) (Pair a d c)
    (***) :: a b c -> a b' c' -> a (Pair a b b') (Pair a c c')
    (&&&) :: a b c -> a b c' -> a b (Pair a c c')
```

And then use the `Arrow`'s proc-notation with my `Arrow` class, but that fails like in the example above of do-notation and `Monad`.

I'll use mostly `Either` as my pair type constructor and not the `(,)` type constructor as with the current `Arrow` class. This might allow to make the code of my toy RTS game (`cabal install DefendTheKind`) much prettier.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You need to use the [NoImplicitPrelude extension](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/6.10-latest/html/users_guide/syntax-extns.html#rebindable-syntax) for full rebindable syntax, including `do` and `proc`. In that case, you get the following, among other stuff:

> "Do" notation is translated using whatever functions (>>=), (>>), and fail, are in scope (not the Prelude versions). List comprehensions, mdo (Section 7.3.6, “The recursive do-notation ”), and parallel array comprehensions, are unaffected.

You can also tweak some handling of negation, equality, literal values, and whatnot. Great way to obfuscate code!

p.s. -- If you're going to rebind the `do` syntax, [what sigfpe calls "parameterized monads"](http://blog.sigfpe.com/2009/02/beyond-monads.html) are great fun. The same idea is available in `category-extras` under [Control.Monad.Indexed](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/category-extras/0.53.5/doc/html/Control-Monad-Indexed.html). And yes, they do work with rebindable syntax, despite the wildly different type signatures!

Comment: awesome, thanks! :) but also, arg! :( too bad that for `Arrow` - "unlike the other constructs, the types of these functions must match the Prelude types very closely", I wonder why is that..

Comment: @yairchu: I imagine it's at least partly due to arrows being less frequently used and the `proc` syntax itself being a more recent addition. As heroic as the GHC team may be, they can't just wave a magic wand to implement every feature that gets thought up...

Comment: The heroism of the GHC team is unparalleled! In fact - they were heroic enough to include Template Haskell! I think I'll try using to make a work-around for this. One will define a "base" Arrow using proc and then use a convertor TH function to make a "generalized" arrow out of it.